# Cannot enter JSON data in ACE editor

Tags: json, editor, ace-editor

I've added the ace editor to my web app running in javascript mode. But I'm not able to enter the closing curly bracket of a JSON object. The editor collapses the entire code until the end of the function.

Example:
var y = {firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Miller'**}**

If I copy this line from another source and paste inside the javascript code all works fine.

Is it a bug? Or is it a configuration problem?
Any idea?

Comment: It's slightly pedantic of me, but that's not a JSON object, it's an object literal inside a JS script. The syntax is the inspiration for JSON, but is not quite the same thing.

Comment: please show example page where this happens